# How do I find the inverse of $f(x) := x^2\ln(1+x^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, inverse, inverse-function

Exercise: Show that $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty), \ f(x) := x^2\ln(1+x^2)$ is bijective.

My approach:

Injectivity: Show that $\mathrm{kernel}(f)=0$.

Surjectivity: I tried to find an inverse function at this point because the following exercise would be to find the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $\ln(2)$.

I tried the usual approach, namely:

$$\begin{align} y &= x^2 \ln(1+x^2) &\leadsto \\ \sqrt{y} &= x \sqrt{\ln(1+x^2)} &\leadsto \\ x &= \frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{\ln(1+x^2)}} ,\end{align}$$

but that didn't help.

I then looked at the inverse functions of both partial functions $x^2$ and $\ln(1+x^2)$ which are $\sqrt{x}=:r$ and $\sqrt{e^x-1}=:s$ because I figured $f^{-1}$ might be $\frac{s}{q}$ or $s \cdot q$, but that turned out to be wrong too.

So how do I find the inverse function? Is there even such an $f^{-1}$ that you can express in terms of elementary functions (going into flawr's answer) or would it simply be better to show the bijectivity without an inverse function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason to expect that there is an inverse in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: It is an exercise and we are supposed to work with the inverse functions after we found it, so I suppose yes, there is such an $f^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't doubt that there is an inverse function $f^{-1}$, at least for $y \in (0,\infty)\$. But I don't think there is one that you can express in terms of elementary functions, which I guess is what you're trying to do.

Comment: The following exercise would be to determine the derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $\ln(2)$, that's why I thought there might be a $f^{-1}$ that you can express in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Well to determine the derivative of the inverse you don't have to have the inverse itself in elementary functions.

Comment: That sheds a new light on it.

Comment: Monotonicity is a different way you could show both injectivity and surjectivity at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the derivative of the inverse we do not necessarily have to have a formula for the inverse itself:

Note that since $t = f(f^{-1}(t))$ by differentiating (assuming $f^{-1}$ exists and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are differentiable) we get

$$ 1 = f'(f^{-1}(t)) \cdot [f^{-1}]'(t)$$

Therefore

$$ [f^{-1}]'(t) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(t))} $$

In your case $f(1) = \ln(2)$ and therefore $f^{-1}(\ln(2)) = 1$.

Therefore

$$ [f^{-1}]'(\ln(2)) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(\ln(2)))} =  \frac{1}{f'(1)}$$

Note that at no point we had to compute $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $e\cdot e^y$ you get a somewhat simplified formula that has the Lambert $W$ function as an inverse.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete form of an inverse? I think the expression seems not trivial even if we use Lambert W function.